# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type mx.collections:IList

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am really very new to flex and am lerning now I got this error while trying to learn to connect my app front end to DB.
Error : 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type mx.collections:IList.

```
private function onDatabaseOpen(event:SQLEvent):void
{
    // init sqlStatement object
    sqlStmt = new SQLStatement();
    sqlStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
    var sql:String =         "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (" +
    "    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "    password TEXT" +
    ")";
    sqlStmt.text = sql;
    sqlStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, statResult);
    sqlStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, createError);
    sqlStmt.execute();
}
private function statResult(event:SQLEvent):void
{
    // refresh data
    var sqlresult:SQLResult = sqlStmt.getResult();

   if(sqlresult.data == null)
   {
    getResult();
    return;
   }

   datafiled.dataProvider = sqlresult.data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to change the last line of your code to:

```
datafiled.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(sqlresult.data);
```

I am not sure what is you "datafield", however I suggest that its property "dataProvider" implements mx.collections:IList interface, so you need to assign an object that also implements mx.collections:IList interface. sqlresult.data is Array and the Array object does not implement this interface. Therefore you should create ArrayCollection out of the Array.
The ArrayCollection implements the needed interface.